# Ansible: Why won't this script log when run through ansible?

Tags: bash, ansible, exec

At the start of a script I have:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>patch_log.out 2>&1
```

(From https://serverfault.com/questions/103501/how-can-i-fully-log-all-bash-scripts-actions)

which when the script is run in the terminal it gives the log file *patch_log.out* I expect
but when running the script from ansible using the shell module it does not (yet I know the rest of the script works correctly)

I imagine it is something to do with my understanding of how exec works, and how I could get it to work through ansible

Comment: The default shell of the shell module is `/bin/sh`. It's possible to use `bash` by passing the executable argument `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Running the script in Ansible**

1. Needed to pass argument to ensure using bash (not sh) (thanks to @U880D)
2. Make sure to set destination directory

So in playbook where I run the script:

```
args:
  executable:
    /bin/bash
  chdir:
    /home/user/directory
```